# VB.NET - Get second hyperlink from string and set as LinkLabel text property

Tags: vb.net

I have a tool that takes in an email and sorts the data into the appropriate fields. In the email, there are normally two hyperlinks that launch the ticket editor in IBM notes. One is a local link and one is a server link. The following code is able to get the local link as it is the first hyperlink that contains 'notes://' but I need to get the one for the server as well, which also starts with 'notes://".

```
   For i = 0 To lines.Count + 1
            If lines(i).StartsWith("notes://") Then
                StartLine = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        link_OpenRequestUsingNotes.Text = lines(StartLine)
```

I thought of writing some code to check the line about it to see if it matches a specific string, maybe with Regex?

For the local link it needs to look for:
"using a Notes client (local replica)"

For the server link it needs to look for:
"using a Notes client (Server):"

The hyperlink is below this text so it would need to look for those and then get the text on the next line.

These links are then set as the text for two link labels that the users can press and go to that link.

If someone could please help me find a way to get the server link, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [`lines.Count + 1` should probably be `lines.Count - 1`.]

Comment: Please put example data into the question; we can't suggest reliable solutions from what you've put, because it will be "coding by trial and error" - we'll suggest something, it works for some of your data, you come back and say "ah, but in this case it doesn't work [insert another nugget of info about the file]", so we modify again.. then you come back again saying what doesn't work now... It's quite a tedious way to help someone when they could make things much easier and better by providing the data we have to parse up front, so that we can work out the edge cases and code for them directly

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes thank you - I realised that, it was an attempt to solve the issue before I posted this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I managed to fix it myself**

Just add 1 to i (StartLine = i + 1) to go to the line below!

```
  'Notes Server Link
    For i = 0 To lines.Count - 1
        If lines(i).StartsWith("Click here to open the request using a Notes client (Server):") Then
            StartLine = i + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    link_OpenServerLink.Text = lines(StartLine)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
link_OpenRequestUsingNotes_Local.Text = "" 'fields for local link
link_OpenRequestUsingNotes_Server.Text = "" 'field for server link

For i = 0 To lines.Count - 1

    If lines(i).StartsWith("using a Notes client (local replica)") Then
        link_OpenRequestUsingNotes_Local.Text = lines(i + 1)
    ElseIf lines(i).StartsWith("using a Notes client (Server)")
        link_OpenRequestUsingNotes_Server.Text = lines(i + 1)
    End If

    If link_OpenRequestUsingNotes_Local.Text <> "" AndAlso link_OpenRequestUsingNotes_Server.Text <> "" Then
        Exit For
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are a few other links after those two, but I only need those two. The code makes the local link go blank and the server link use the last link in the string copied from the email

Comment: I  have completely modified my answer to implements your idea! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use code like this to find the first two links:

```
Dim notes = Function(x) x.StartsWith("notes://")
Dim index As Integer = lines.FindIndex(notes)
If index <> -1 AndAlso index < (lines.Count - 1) Then
    Dim firstLink As String = lines(index + 1)
    ' ... do something with "firstLink"...
    Debug.Print(firstLink)

    index = lines.FindIndex(index + 2, notes)
    If index <> -1 AndAlso index < (lines.Count - 1) Then
        Dim secondLink As String = lines(index + 1)
        ' ... do something with "secondLink"...
        Debug.Print(secondLink)
    End If
End If
```